# Laravel - local.ERROR: Error: Call to undefined function App\Imports\create() in Excel Import

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel-8 and Maatwebsite-3.1 package for excel upload:

I have this Excel sheet (The data is more thank that):

[image: excel]

imports:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\DefaultValueBinder;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Throwable;

class EmployeeImport extends DefaultValueBinder implements OnEachRow, WithStartRow, SkipsOnError, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure, WithEvents, WithCustomValueBinder
{
  // set the preferred date format
  private $date_format = 'Y-m-d';

  // set the columns to be formatted as
  private $date_columns = ['E'];

use Importable, SkipsErrors, SkipsFailures;

public function onRow(Row $row)
{
    $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();
    if($rowIndex >= 1000)
        return; // Not more than 1000 rows at a time

    $row = $row->toArray();

    $employee_data = [
        'first_name'                        => $row[0],
        'other_name'                        => $row[1] ?? '',
        'last_name'                         => $row[2],
        'email'                             => preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($row[3])),
        'dob'                               => $this->transformDate($row[4]),
    ];

    $employee = create(Employee::class, $employee_data);

    if (User::where('email', '=', $employee->email)->exists()) {
        $user = User::update([
            'first_name'                        => $employee->first_name,
            'last_name'                         => $employee->last_name,
            'active'                            => 1,
        ]);
     }else{
        $user = User::create([
            'email'                             => $employee->email,
            'first_name'                        => $employee->first_name,
            'last_name'                         => $employee->last_name,
            'active'                            => 1,
        ]);
     }
    $employee->update([
        'user_id'           => $user->id,
    ]);
}

public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}

public function customValidationAttributes()
{
    return [
        '0'     => 'First Name',
        '1'     => 'Other Name',
        '2'     => 'Last Name',
        '3'     => 'Email',
        '4'     => 'Date of Birth',
    ];
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '*.0' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:50'
        ],
        '*.1' => [
            'nullable',
            'string',
            'max:50'
        ],
        '*.2' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:50'
        ],
        '*.3' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            'max:100',
            Rule::unique('employees', 'email')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id);
            })
        ],
        '*.4' => [
            'required',
            'date_format:Y-m-d',
           'before:' . Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d')
        ],
    ];
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}

public function transformDate($value, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    try {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value));
    } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
    }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public function importEmployee(Request $request)
{
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'document' => 'file|mimes:xls,xlsx|max:5000',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('document'))
        {
            if($validator->passes()) {

                $import = new EmployeeImport;
                $file = $request->file('document');

                $file->move(public_path('storage/employee_imports'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
                Excel::import($import, public_path('storage/employee_imports/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() ));

                return $this->success('Employees Imported.', [
                    'file'         => $file
                ]);
            }else{
                return $this->error($validator->errors(), 422);
            }
        }
}
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

```
[2021-08-19 09:33:40] local.ERROR: Error: Call to undefined function 
App\Imports\create() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Imports\EmployeeImport.php:98
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Sheet.php(301): 
App\Imports\EmployeeImport->onRow(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Reader.php(114): Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet->import(Object(App\Imports\EmployeeImport), 2)
#2
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Concerns\ManagesTransactions.php(29): Maatwebsite\Excel\Reader->Maatwebsite\Excel{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection))

This is the line 98:

> $employee = create(Employee::class, $employee_data);

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$employee = create(Employee::class, $employee_data);
```

to

```
$employee = Employee::create($employee_data);
```

`create` is not a function alone. Check this link
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models